# Is it possible to disable category output in .NET Core ConsoleLogger and DebugLogger?

Tags: logging, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm using a very typical (I think) setup for logging in a .NET Core console app I'm writing:

```
services.AddLogging(loggingBuilder => {
    loggingBuilder.AddConfiguration(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
    loggingBuilder.AddConsole();
    loggingBuilder.AddDebug();
});
```

To my eyes, the default output is difficult to read because it is polluted with contextual information that is of no interest to me:

Console (everything on the first line is unwanted noise):

```
info: MyApp.MyNamespace.OtherNamespace[0]
      The message I actually want to see
```

Debug (everything up to `Information:` is unwanted noise):

```
MyApp.MyNamespace.OtherNamespace:Information: The message I actually want to see
```

I assumed it would be easy to turn off this excess contextual information but so far I'm drawing a blank. Is it possible to disable this stuff short of writing a custom implementation of both ConsoleLogger and DebugLogger? (at which point it'd probably just be easier to use Log4Net).

Comment: Note: having now studied the source of the code in question on Github I can see that what I'm trying to do here is impossible, which I find really surprising because I'm sure I can't be the first person to not want my logger to add a load of "extra" stuff to the strings I give it. I've since written replacement implementations of the ConsoleLogger and DebugLogger which do what I want. I'll post them here as an answer shortly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's what I ended up writing to solve this problem (makes use of [Crayon](https://github.com/riezebosch/crayon) to colour the console output):

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using Crayon;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace Kope.Pilot.Hrs.Utils.Logging
{
    public class CleanConsoleLogger : ILogger
    {
        public LogLevel LogLevel { get; set; } = LogLevel.Information;

        public IDisposable BeginScope<TState>(TState state) => null;

        public bool IsEnabled(LogLevel logLevel) => logLevel >= this.LogLevel;

        public void Log<TState>(LogLevel logLevel, EventId eventId, TState state, Exception exception, Func<TState, Exception, string> formatter)
        {
            if (!IsEnabled(logLevel))
                return;

            string message = formatter(state, exception);
            if (exception != null)
                message += $"{Environment.NewLine}{exception}";

            switch (logLevel)
            {
                case LogLevel.Trace:
                    Console.Out.WriteLineAsync(Output.Bright.Black(message));
                    break;
                case LogLevel.Debug:
                    Console.Out.WriteLineAsync(Output.Bright.Black(message));
                    break;
                case LogLevel.Information:
                    Console.Out.WriteLineAsync(message);
                    break;
                case LogLevel.Warning:
                    Console.Out.WriteLineAsync(Output.Dim().Yellow().Text(message));
                    break;
                case LogLevel.Error:
                    Console.Error.WriteLineAsync(Output.Bright.Red(message));
                    break;
                case LogLevel.Critical:
                    Console.Error.WriteLineAsync(Output.Bright.Red(message));
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    public class CleanConsoleLoggerProvider : ILoggerProvider
    {
        private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, CleanConsoleLogger> _loggers = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, CleanConsoleLogger>();
        
        public ILogger CreateLogger(string categoryName)
            => _loggers.GetOrAdd(categoryName, name => new CleanConsoleLogger());

        public void Dispose()
        {
            _loggers.Clear();
        }
    }

    public static class CleanConsoleLoggerFactoryExtensions
    {

        public static ILoggingBuilder AddCleanConsole(this ILoggingBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.Services.AddSingleton<ILoggerProvider, CleanConsoleLoggerProvider>();
            return builder;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I need do this much just to get rid of that xxxxx[0] head?

Comment: Thanks for this, it works great! Unfortunately, this logger won't allow for changing the log level with this line:
`public LogLevel LogLevel { get; set; } = LogLevel.Information;`

When I remove the default value, my settings file can now control the `LogLevel`

Answer (score 0):

You can now create a custom formatter by extending `ConsoleFormatter`. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/console-log-formatter#implement-a-custom-formatter

The example code given works fine.

There are also links to the source code for the stock formatters. I ended up taking a copy of the source code for the `SimpleConsoleFormatter.cs` and just ripping out the line which prints the category.

Answer (score -3):

```
    ILoggerFactory loggerFactory = LoggerFactory.Create(builder =>
    {
        builder.AddSimpleConsole(o=>o.SingleLine=true); // <-- BINGO
```

Comment: Code-only answers are not particularly useful; please edit your post to explain what your code does and how that answer's the question.

Comment: This suggestion just removes the line break of each log entry, but not the "unwanted noise"